# Setting content-type header with restify results in application/octet-stream

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm trying out [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/), and though I'm more comfortable with Express, so far it's pretty awesome. I'm trying to set the content type header in the response like so:

```
server.get('/xml', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/xml');
    // res.header('content-type', 'application/xml'); // tried this too
    // res.contentType = "application/xml"; // tried this too
    res.send("<root><test>stuff</test></root>");
});
```

But the response I get back is instead `application/octet-stream`.

I also tried [`res.contentType('application/xml')`](https://gentlenode.com/journal/node-3-restify-cheatsheet/44) but that actually threw an error (`"Object HTTP/1.1 200 OK\ has no method 'contentType'"`).

What is the correct way to set the content type header to xml on the response?

**Update:**

When I do `console.log(res.contentType);` it actually outputs `application/xml`. Why is it not in the response headers?

**Curl snippet:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /xml?params=1,2,3 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 8995
< Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 20:20:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<body goes here>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of `curl` or `httpie` command line testing this? You should confirm you are really hitting the server side code you think you are hitting.

Comment: @PeterLyons added. Moreover, in response to your answer, there are several instances around the web where all three of those options are used to set the headers o_O all three have the same outcome as well, setting the headers to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Thanks. Only thing I can think of is try using the correct case for "Content-Type". Otherwise this small example should be fine, or there's something else in your setup (like forgot to restart the server so you are running an old version of the code or something) tripping you up.

Comment: @PeterLyons yeah, tried uppercase too, and I know the server is running the correct copy of code because I added in the console log.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out the reason this was failing is because I was not sending the response using `Restify`'s response handler; it was defaulting to the native Node.js handler.

Where I was doing this:

```
res.send(js2xmlparser("search", obj));
```

I should have been doing this:

```
res.end(js2xmlparser("search", o));
//  ^ end, not send!
```

Comment: Do u have any explanation, why this happens like this?

Comment: Nope - I presume it was just an oversight (or intentionally designed).

Comment: I have the same issue, but `end`ing doesn't fix for me, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> When I do console.log(res.contentType); it actually outputs application/xml. Why is it not in the response headers?

All you've done there is set a property on the `res` object. And because this is JavaScript, that works fine and you can read the property value back, but that's not the correct API for either node core or restify, so it is ignored by everything other than your code.

Your `res.header("Content-Type", "application/xml");` looks correct to me based on the restify docs you linked to. Therefore my hunch is your tooling may be misleading you. Are you sure you are seeing the raw values in the response (many developer tools will unhelpfully "prettify" or otherwise lie to you) and you are hitting the route you really think you are? Output of `curl -v` or `httpie --headers` would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to return application/xml by adding a formatter to the server instance at server creation:

```
var server  = restify.createServer( {
   formatters: {
       'application/xml' : function( req, res, body, cb ) {
           if (body instanceof Error)
              return body.stack;

           if (Buffer.isBuffer(body))
              return cb(null, body.toString('base64'));

           return cb(null, body);
       }
  } 
});
```

Then at some part of the code:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/xml');
res.send('<xml>xyz</xml>');
```

Please, take a look at: http://restify.com/#content-negotiation

Answer (score 1):

You can send the XML response using [**sendRaw**](http://restify.com/docs/response-api/#sendraw) instead of **send**. The **sendRaw**  method doesn't use any formatter at all (you should preformat your response if you need it). See an example below:

```
server.get('/xml', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/xml');
  res.sendRaw('<xml>xyz</xml>');
  next();
});
```